# Re-exporting ES6 modules in TS 1.7?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, typescript1.7

I'm getting a bit lost in TS re-exports. Say I create a pair of test modules;

test1.ts;

```
export function test1() {
    return 'test';
}
```

test2.ts;

```
export function test2() {
    return 'test';
}
```

I believe I should be able to then do something like this;

combined.ts;

```
export * from './test1';
export * from './test2';

module.exports = {
    test1: test1,
    test2: test2
};
```

But, no such luck. There seem to be lots of GitHub issues discussing various approaches to this, including an old hack using `export import * from './test1'` but they all seem to argue what the ES6 spec really means, and none actually work..

What's the right way to do a rollup like this? Am I just going down the wrong path to split a module up across files? Are namespaces more appropriate here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You shouldn’t be using `module.exports` when you are working with ES modules; `module.exports` is a part of CommonJS modules, not a part of EcmaScript modules.

### Rollup, exporting directly

Your correct rollup module will simply be:

```ts
export * from './test1';
export * from './test2';
```

Then to use the rollup:

```ts
import * as rollup from './combined';
// or `import { test1, test2 } from './combined'`;
// or any other valid import

rollup.test1();
rollup.test2();
```

### Rollup, adding namespace objects

If you want to export test1 and test2 with extra namespacing then use `export {}` syntax:

```ts
import * as test1 from './test1';
import * as test2 from './test2';
export { test1, test2 };
```

Then usage becomes:

```ts
import * as rollup from './combined';
rollup.test1.test1();
rollup.test2.test2();
```

### Rollup, using different export names

You can also redirect names using `as` if you have some name conflict, just like with `import`:

```ts
export { test1 as t1 } from './test1';
export { test2 as t2 } from './test2';
```

Then usage becomes:

```ts
import * as rollup from './combined';
rollup.t1();
rollup.t2();
```

Comment: So this makes perfect sense, except one thing -- is index.js a CommonJS thing as well? If I do my rollup in util/index.js, doing import * from '../util' doesnt work -- ../util/index does.. Is this an ES6 thing? My tsconfig is set to module: commonjs if that matters..

Comment: Implicit loading of an index.js file is a Node.js-specific thing. Best not to rely on that functionality, especially since you could have e.g. util.js file *plus* a util directory with an index.js file.

Comment: so that's what I was about to do -- util.js in the top-level dir that does export * from 'util/<whatever' but once i have a non-trivial number of modules, my top-level will get pretty ugly.. is there a better way to split up util?

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks for this answer. The roll up with namespace was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can not export everything in a module using *, not even if you use * as localModuleName.

Instead you have to name what your the combined module exports from the other modules.

```js
// combined.ts
export {test1, test3} from './test1'; 
export {test2} from './test2';
```