# How to export multiple imported classes as a module

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have 2 classes, A and B, implemented in 2 different files: A.ts and B.ts (both exporting just the class instance implemented in them).

I would like to export them both in a third file C.ts:

```
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";
export module mymodule {
    export A;
    export B;
}
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't compile..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-exporting ES6 modules in TS 1.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557587/re-exporting-es6-modules-in-ts-1-7)

Comment: @geochr Same issue as yours, wonder if you found a solution.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh Yea we did 
Inside the exported mymodule you go :
export type AExported = A;
export const AExported = A;

This allows you to export A as mymodule.AExported

Answer (score 1):

In `C.ts`, do

```
export * from './A'
export * from './B'
```

When importing C, definitions from `A` and `B` will be available too.

There is one caveat: you cannot re-export `default` exports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking to export A and B in a new namespace though .

Comment: OK. Not sure what your objective is but have you read this (last sentence)?: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/namespaces.html. You should not mix namespaces and external modules... and actually most likely not use namespaces at all. In `D` you can `import * as ns from './C'` and `ns` is your namespace

Comment: I have several classes that I want to organize into modules via a single file. So C would actually have to export multiple modules. Not sure if this is possible now.